# node.js process manager (pm2) infinite loop error on FreeBSD

Tags: node.js, unix, freebsd

When I try start process pm2 test.js or pm2 web (does not matter), pm2 returns the following error:

> Error retrieving process list: Error: Looks like a process in on
>   infinite loop, wait 10s to get more informations

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: You'll have a better time asking the package author on [the pm2 repository](https://github.com/unitech/pm2)

Comment: Seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/162